# Rails How To Catch Exceptions for Database Connection Unavailability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

I have a Rails application and I'm trying to catch exceptions when the database server is down on my shared hosting so that I can understand the performance of my server in general. To do that, I have set up the exception_notification gem from https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification and in my ApplicationController, I have the following code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :check_database

  rescue_from Exception do |exception|
    ExceptionNotifier::Notifier \
        .exception_notification(request.env, exception) \
        .deliver
    raise exception
  end

  private

  def check_database
    Category.first
  rescue Exception => exception
    ExceptionNotifier::Notifier \
        .exception_notification(request.env, exception) \
        .deliver
    raise exception
  end

end
```

However, none of the rescue blocks worked for me. Can you kindly advise how I can catch such an exception in Rails? Thanks

Comment: what do you mean not they didn't work? Also for rescue I believe you would need a `begin` e.g. `begin; Category.first; rescue ...` also if you know the type of exception you are trying to rescue I would specify it explicitly although it is not as imperative since you do properly re-raise after the logging.

Comment: Sure I will try to catch the most specific exceptions with respect to my application. However, this is only for testing and because it's not working I had to try to catch Exception as the root class of all exceptions. I said it's not working because when I try to shut down the database server, none of the code blocks sent email to my email address regarding the error. Instead it just showed the error page when accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Standard practice in Ruby is to make application level exceptions inherit from `StandardError` instead of `Exception`. This is so that rescuing them will not cause important system-level problems to be hidden. You can see examples from Rails [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=standarderror&type=Code). That's why your blocks are not working.

Either replace `Exception` with `StandardError`, or even better, use a debugger to pause on one of those lines and step through the code when the database is not available. You should find your self in some sort of rescue block and be able to see the class of the actual error that's raised so that you can use that. You could also dig through the active record source code to find the correct class name if you want ;)

Comment: Sure I will try to catch the most specific exceptions with respect to my application. However, I couldn't get both the rescue blocks to send emails to me when I shut down the database server as a simulation to database server down problem. Hence, I catched Exception as the root class. Still can you please tell me why it didn't catch the PG::Error exception. I'm using Postgres.